# Setting 4X2 figures in a page

Tags: floats

I can't have all the images (4X2) in one page, while it works for 6 images (3X2) and there is enough space in the page. Any suggestion please?

```
    \begin{figure}[ht] 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{images/changes/R1_N_Net1.pdf} 
    \caption{\footnotesize Network 1, Hill-function-based method} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_N_1} 
    \vspace{4ex}
  \end{subfigure}%% 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{images/changes/R1_N_Net4.pdf} 
    \caption{\footnotesize Network 4, Hill-function-based method} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_N_4} 
    \vspace{4ex}
  \end{subfigure} 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{images/changes/R1_N_Net_r2.pdf} 
    \caption{\footnotesize Network 2, Not fixed half-lives} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_N_r_2} 
    \vspace{4ex}
  \end{subfigure} 
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{images/changes/R1_N_Net_r6.pdf} 
    \caption{\footnotesize Network 6, Not fixed half-lives} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_N_r_6} 
    \vspace{4ex}
  \end{subfigure} 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{images/changes/R1_N_Net8.pdf} 
    \caption{\footnotesize Network 8, Hill-function-based method} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_N_8} 
  \end{subfigure}%%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{images/changes/R1_C_Net2.pdf} 
    \caption{\footnotesize Network 2, gene circuit method} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_C_2} 
  \end{subfigure} 
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{images/changes/R1_C_Net5.pdf} 
    \caption{\footnotesize Network 5, gene circuit method} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_C_5} 
  \end{subfigure}%%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{images/changes/R1_C_Net7.pdf} 
    \caption{\footnotesize Network 7, gene circuit method} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_C_7} 
  \end{subfigure} 
  \caption[Knockdown of proposed interactions in region R1]{\footnotesize Knockdown of proposed interactions in region R1}
  \label{fig:output of knock R1} 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Having asked 15 questions before, you should know that a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is necessary for questions like yours.

Comment: you are missing a `%` here `\end{subfigure} ` and it would be simpler if you left a blank line after the first two rather than rely on tex linebreaking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of specifying the widths of the images within the `subfigure` environments, you could specify their *heights*. Also, don't insert `\vspace{4ex}` inside each `subfigure`; it suffices to insert this directive immediately before subfigures 3, 5, and 7. With captions for each `subfigure` as well as for the `figure` as a whole, and taking into account the extra vertical spacing brought about by the `\vspace{4ex}` instructions, an image height of `0.18\textheight` appears to assure that the entire `figure` environment will fit on a page without the `figure` exceeding the margins of the text block.

Separately, since it looks like (though I can't be sure, as you haven't posted a full MWE) you're using the `subcaption` environment, you should provide the instruction

```
\captionsetup[figure]{size=footnotesize}
```

in the preamble. This saves you nine `\footnotesize` directives later on (8 subfigures, 1 figure). By going this route, you also avoid a (presumably unwanted) difference in font size for the string "Figure 1:" vs. the remainder of the caption. And, if you decide to change the font size for figure and subfigure captions to, say, "small", you can make the change by changing a single setting in the preamble instead of having to go through lots and lots of `\caption` directives.

Finally, I can't help but remark that I've noticed that the subfigure captions' text is not in sync with their (alphabetical) numbering. This might confuse some of your readers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % leave off "demo" option in real document
\usepackage{subcaption} % for "subfigure" environment
\captionsetup[figure]{size=footnotesize}
   %% font size for figure and subfigure captions
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % leave off "showframe" option in real document
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]    
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.18\textheight]{images/changes/R1_N_Net1.pdf} 
    \caption{Network 1, Hill-function-based method} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_N_1} 
  \end{subfigure} 
  \hspace{\fill}  %% maximize space between adjacent subfigures
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.18\textheight]{images/changes/R1_N_Net4.pdf} 
    \caption{Network 4, Hill-function-based method} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_N_4} 
  \end{subfigure} 

  \vspace{4ex}  %% extra vertical space
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.18\textheight]{images/changes/R1_N_Net_r2.pdf} 
    \caption{Network 2, Not fixed half-lives} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_N_r_2} 
  \end{subfigure} 
  \hspace{\fill}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.18\textheight]{images/changes/R1_N_Net_r6.pdf} 
    \caption{Network 6, Not fixed half-lives} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_N_r_6} 
  \end{subfigure} 

    \vspace{4ex}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.18\textheight]{images/changes/R1_N_Net8.pdf} 
    \caption{Network 8, Hill-function-based method} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_N_8} 
  \end{subfigure}
  \hspace{\fill}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.18\textheight]{images/changes/R1_C_Net2.pdf} 
    \caption{Network 2, gene circuit method} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_C_2} 
  \end{subfigure} 

    \vspace{4ex}
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.18\textheight]{images/changes/R1_C_Net5.pdf} 
    \caption{Network 5, gene circuit method} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_C_5} 
  \end{subfigure}
  \hspace{\fill}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.18\textheight]{images/changes/R1_C_Net7.pdf} 
    \caption{Network 7, gene circuit method} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_C_7} 
  \end{subfigure} 

\caption{Knockdown of proposed interactions in region R1}
\label{fig:output of knock R1} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works without
\captionsetup[subfigure]{size=footnotesize}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} when I leave them, all my pages go into frames.

Comment: @Maryam - I've updated the example to explain what the "showframe" option of the `geometry` package does (and that it should be omitted in the real document). I've also added a further explanation to the suggestion of using `\captionsetup[subfigure]{size=footnotesize}`.