# How do you get a 4x2 subfigure?

Tags: subfloats

I want to get a 4 row x 2 column subfigure but I can't figure out how to even get 2 images side by side. I've copied and pasted code from the help page and from various help sites but nothing works. The images are stacking below each other, rather than getting 2 columns. Here is an example of my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}
\graphicspath{Figures/}  % Location of the graphics files (set up for graphics 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/2µm_lines_CA_graph}
        \caption{Contact angle with various pseudo dosages}
        \label{fig:2µm_lines_CA_graph}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill etc. 
      %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)

    \begin{subfigure}[]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/2µm_lines_CAH_graph}
        \caption{Contact angle with various pseudo dosages}
        \label{fig:2µm_lines_CAH_graph}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Contact angles on 2 $\mu$m Lines}\label{fig:2µm_lines_CA_graphs}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't leave blank lines in your figure environment, they will be interpreted as new line

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! This question isen't new, so see (for example)  [Setting 4X2 figures in a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210769/124842)

Comment: Unrelated: each path in `\graphicspath` should be enclosed in a pair of braces, so you should have `\graphicspath{{Figures/}}`.

Answer (score 2):

- your question is duplicate to many similar question here, for example as note  Bobyandbob in his comment [setting-4x2-figures-in-a-page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210767/setting-4x2-figures-in-a-page/210769#210769)
- beside this you have some (off-topic) problems:

  - for `subfigure` environments You need to load `subcaption` package (I don't know if used document class `thesis` do this)
  - loading of `subfig` is superfluous (it is not compatible with `subcaption`)
  - images with width of `subfigure` environment has no sense to center in it

consider aforementioned, your MWE become

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}% i haven't thesis document class
%\graphicspath{Figures/}  % Location of the graphics files (set up for graphics

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/2µm_lines_CA_graph}
        \caption{Contact angle with various pseudo dosages}
        \label{fig:2µm_lines_CA_graph}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/2µm_lines_CAH_graph}
        \caption{Contact angle with various pseudo dosages}
        \label{fig:2µm_lines_CAH_graph}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/2µm_lines_CA_graph}
        \caption{Contact angle with various pseudo dosages}
        \label{fig:2µm_lines_CA_graph}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/2µm_lines_CAH_graph}
        \caption{Contact angle with various pseudo dosages}
        \label{fig:2µm_lines_CAH_graph}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/2µm_lines_CA_graph}
        \caption{Contact angle with various pseudo dosages}
        \label{fig:2µm_lines_CA_graph}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/2µm_lines_CAH_graph}
        \caption{Contact angle with various pseudo dosages}
        \label{fig:2µm_lines_CAH_graph}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/2µm_lines_CA_graph}
        \caption{Contact angle with various pseudo dosages}
        \label{fig:2µm_lines_CA_graph}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/2µm_lines_CAH_graph}
        \caption{Contact angle with various pseudo dosages}
        \label{fig:2µm_lines_CAH_graph}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Contact angles on 2 $\mu$m Lines}\label{fig:2µm_lines_CA_graphs}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```